# css class applied only for one button

Tags: javascript, css, button

When I scroll, I want to keep my buttons (2) fixed in the page.

This is my `JavaScript` function:

```
function init() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
    var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
        shrinkOn = 350,
        btn = document.querySelector("button");
    if (distanceY > ShrinkOn) {
      btn.setAttribute("class", "fixed_btn");
    }
    else
      btn.removeAttribute("class");
  });
}
window.onload = init();
```

And the `CSS` of `fixed_btn`:

```
.fixed_btn {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

It works, but `fixed_btn` class is applied only for the first button, the second one remain in the same position (it goes up when scrolling).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`querySelector` selects only the first match of the given selector. You want to use `querySelectorAll`, which returns all elements that match the selector. ([docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll))

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
```

Comment: Now, I get these javascript errors: `btns.setAttribute is not a function` and `btns.removeAttribute is not a function`

Comment: Because `querySelectorAll` is matching multiple items, `btns` is an array, not just one element as it was before. If you *know* there are two buttons, you can refer to each element explicitly (i.e. `btns[0].setAttribute ... ; btns[1].setAttribute ...;`), If there may be more than two, you should loop over the `btns` array and call those functions on each item.

Comment: I found out that btns is a node.

Comment: It's not a `Node`, it is a `NodeList`. See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) for ways to loop over it.

Comment: Now, the position of buttons is fixed. The problem is that now they are overlapping. How to put one next to each other?

Comment: That's a different problem entirely. First try [searching stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=position+two+divs+next+to+each+other), and if that doesn't help, ask a new question.